# Asterisk not playing custom sounds on Ubuntu Server 11.04

Tags: server, asterisk

I've installed Asterisk on my Ubuntu Server, all works fine, excepts playing the custom sounds.

Asterisk sounds work, but this file I've uploaded does not play (on other servers it works, it is a .WAV PCM 16bit 8000).

Here is some log output:

```
[Feb  6 22:55:45] WARNING[11045] file.c: File custom/sohoitsoluciones does not exist in any format
[Feb  6 22:55:45] WARNING[11045] file.c: Unable to open custom/sohoitsoluciones (format 0x4 (ulaw)): No such file or directory
[Feb  6 22:55:45] WARNING[11045] app_playback.c: ast_streamfile failed on SIP/Out4903-0000001d for custom/sohoitsoluciones
```

How can I get Asterisk to play a custom sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk is looking in the wrong place for the recordings. You can fix this with:

```
mv /usr/local/share/asterisk/sounds /usr/local/share/asterisk/sounds.old
```

followed by

```
ln -s /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/custom /usr/local/share/asterisk/sounds
chown -R asterisk:asterisk /usr/local/share/asterisk/
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/asterisk/
```

I found this here: http://www.freepbx.org/forum/freepbx/installation/ivr-not-working

Comment: there is not directory /usr/local/share/asterisk

this answer is not correct.